# filtering lists with formulas takes a while, even when calculation is set to manual

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, speed

Why is this, and is there a fix for it?  The only workaround I have at the moment is to keep the formula in the top row, and do the rest as paste values.

Comment: "is there a fix for it?" - it's quite difficult to answer without knowing more details.

Comment: what do you want to know?  If you have a filtered list with many rows, containing formulas, excel (2010) hangs for a while when any filter operations are performed.  If these are pasted as values, it doesn't.  This applies to pretty much anything, for me, it's usually rows of lookups

Comment: What many means for you?  How many columns?  Do you have array formulas?  How many of the columns contains formulas?  Do you have also other sheets with many data in your workbook?  ...